# How to deny Insert permissions on a table to all users except few in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `TableABC`. I'd like to grant `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE` to the group `ReleaseTeam`, but I want all the other users to have the `INSERT, DELETE` and `UPDATE` permission denied.

I don't know how many other users there are in the system. I just know that `ReleaseTeam` should be the only one to have DML permissions on that table.

Comment: Permissions that are not granted are denied.

Comment: Well, I thought the same. I Granted the UserGroup "ReleaseTeam" Permissions with this Command "GRANT INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE ON [dbo].[TableABC] TO [ReleaseTeam] WITH GRANT OPTION". But when I login as myself, who's not a member of ReleaseTeam, tries to do an INSERT on TableABC, it lets me INSERT.

Comment: Then your `USER` or a `ROLE` (including `public`) your `USER` belongs to has permission to `INSERT` as well. What @GSerg is true.

Comment: On that Database, I don't see any other `USER` or `ROLE` which has INSERT Permission except "ReleaseTeam". I searched for `public` as well but it has a lot of SELECT Permissions and a few EXECUTE Permissions but no INSERT Permission.

Comment: Are you a `sysadmin`, @GaryTheBrave ?

Comment: I can't post a fiddle, as creating a `USER` isn't allowed, but you can see from [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Rvae.png) the only person denied is `User3`, as they weren't granted permission to `INSERT`.

Comment: @Larnu: I was suspecting the same. But my user login is not on the Server's Logins to begin with. And I checked a few user groups that I'm part of. But those user groups also did not have a `sysadmin` role. They all had `public` role. And `public` role did not have any INSERT permissions on both the `master` database as well my Database. :(

Comment: *Something* is giving you permissions, @GaryTheBrave . I *assume* that you aren't stating you have permission to `INSERT` because you're actually executing a procedure that is inserting? If so, then the insert permissions may well not be relevant at all due to ownership chaining.

Comment: Is your `LOGIN` a windows login as well? Don't forget, AD groups can be created as both `USER`s and `ROLE`s and as an AD User you will inherit any permissions those AD Groups have too. Perhaps an AD Group that is a `USER` has permissions to `INSERT`. Only you have access to your instance to find out, but *something* is giving you permission.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu for that example. I greatly appreciate your effort in helping me out. And I'm unfortunately running a simple INSERT statement, not via an SP. As you and GSerg mentioned that "**Permissions that are not granted are denied**", I'll keep digging to find which user group or role that is tied to my login is giving me insert permission on that Table. It has to be on the Database Level or Server Level. Thanks again. I'll keep you posted with what I find.

Comment: FWIW, permission paths can be tricky. I tend to use sys.user_token to see all the ways I could get permissions and sys.fn_my_permissions to determine effective permissions.

Comment: Put it this way: what permissions are allowing DML on *any* of the tables? Clearly someone can login and access the database, what is allowing them to do that?